# Is it possible at all to record audio in AAC/MP4 format on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, encoding, audio, aac

In this link it says it does:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html

However I have searched for an example that works on the web and can only see people complaining they can't get it to work. I have a working AudioQueue example for PCM but the very moment I switch this to AAC initialization fails. SpeakHere example also only uses PCM.

Has anyone ever managed to make this work or has a link to a code snippet that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically iPhone only record PCM. To get an AAC encoded file the original PCM stream should be stored into a AudioFile and then this AudioFile should be converted to AAC.

There's no way to record and convert on the fly on iPhone unless you include a third-party library that will do this for you.